# How do I store data in the resource section of a C++ executable?

Tags: c++, resources, executable

I'm struggling to find any helpful resources on how I can use the resource section within a executable to store and retrieve data.

If anybody would be kind enough to explain it and possibly provide some sample code, I would be most grateful.

Edit - Working with Windows Visual c++ 2008.

Comment: What OS are you working with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The executable format depends on your OS, not your programming language.  Is this a Windows PE format file?  A Linux ELF file?

Comment: Have you considered using a separate data file instead?  Is there a particular reason to need to store data in the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a portable way to encode files in an executable: you encode your files in specific structure. Ex:

```
// header MyFile.h
static const int fileSizeInBytes = 42;
extern const unsigned char myFileContents[fileSizeInBytes];

// source MyFile.cpp
const unsigned char myFileContents[fileSizeInBytes] =
{
    0x0A, 0x35, 0x25, //...
    // ...
    0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF
};
```

You can find some tools for automatically generating those files (for example, with Qt, there is rcc).

Also, there is a [more specific answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072455/windows-pe-resources) (Windows, PE format). You can also [look here](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=34291) (although it's for the Irrlicht Engine, the code is rather clear and small, easily understandable) (still for PE format).
I don't know for the ELF format.