# Editing embeded resources file dll using c#

Tags: embedded-resource

I have a compiled DLL that contains a string resource.
I don't have access to the source code of the dll, but I wish to change that
resource. How can I do that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072455/windows-pe-resources

Comment: Also: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+pe+resource+editor

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it in C++.  If so, you can also do it in C# (via Interop).

Look here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Look at [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends.